# How to iterate through a Set<Enum>

Tags: java

```java
public enum Gears {
    DRIVE,
    PARK,
    NEUTRAL,
    REVERSE
}

int[] values = new int[] {1,2,3,4}

public class ValidCombinations(Gears gear, int number)
```

How do I iterate through every possible combination of `Gears` and `values`?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax appears illegal on your class definition. But assuming you just want all possible combinations of `Gears` and `Values` in a `Set` of `ValidCombinations` you could use a pair of nested for loops and something like

```
Set<ValidCombinations> set = new HashSet<>();
for (Gears g : Gears.values()) {
    for (int v : values) {
        set.add(new ValidCombinations(g, v));
    }
}
```